# Created a data frame for each column

Tags: r, function, filter, tidyverse

how to created a data frame for each column that contains  rows with all non zero in R

[image]

This is the output desired

[image]

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I created your data in data frame and then created the output you want to have. Here is the data frame:

```
one <- c(0,0,1)
two <- c(1,1,1)
three <- c(1,0,1)
Var_one <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
df <- data.frame(Var_one,one, two, three)
df
```

The solution is as follows:

```
d1 <- df %>% select(c(Var_one, one))
d1[apply(d1!=0, 1, all),]
d2 <- df %>% select(c(Var_one, two))
d2[apply(d2!=0, 1, all),]
d3 <- df %>% select(c(Var_one, three))
d3[apply(d3!=0, 1, all),]
```